# Auto-Join Rooms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

It would be really helpful if I didn't have to manually join the rooms I'm interested in every time I launch chat. What I'd suggest is one of two mechanisms for auto-joining chat rooms.

**Auto-Join Favorites**
Make a setting so that you will automatically join rooms you mark as 'favorites'.

**Remember Rooms**
Automatically join the rooms you were in last time. (I'd prefer this one)

This way you don't have to reopen all the chat rooms you want to be active in, you simply log in and they are already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both good suggestions. The "rejoin favorites" is something that has been suggested a few times; makes sense, so I guess that'll be a no brainer. The "rejoin where I was last time" *also* isn't necessarily taxing - just store when you click "leave all" and job done.

I think we'll inevitably get *something* here.

Comment: This has been [tag:status-completed], but I don't see any feature like this. Where is this implemented? Or is this planned? I'm having [a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116378/can-it-be-made-easier-to-join-all-chats-or-switch-faster-between-chats) which this feature would solve...

Comment: @Tom it is the link that "rejoin favorites" points to, if you don't let JavaScript hijack it (to do the submit); specifically http://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/join/favorite

Comment: Ah, but that's not automatically. The problem is that I don't see that button in the chat window anymore when my browser opens up two chats by default (application tabs in Firefox).

Comment: @Tom define "automatically"? It would, for example, be very inadviseable to do this on just a GET. To get the button, you need to be off the "favourites" tab. Let me know what exactly it is you are looking for here...

Comment: Under my context I would understand that it happens when I open my browser and thus that the two application tabs are loaded, so the first tab just joins all the rooms. But I think that under your context it would only mean not having to join each separate room manually. My problem is described in [the first part of my question here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116378/145350) as well as [reproduction steps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116381/145350) in the last comment to Fezziwig's answer.

Comment: **In short:** If I have two chat rooms that load when my browser opens, I have to "first go to the front page and then click the button and then refresh both tabs" in order to consistently in all chat rooms. This requires to load three times, which could otherwise be a single click and a single load. Other people solve this [by just opening all the rooms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116378/can-it-be-made-easier-to-join-all-chats-or-switch-faster-between-chats#comment-304294) which result in request floods, which I think are unacceptable...