# SO Blog Magic Links for Chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, onebox

Hey can we get blog.stackoverflow.com to be a magic link too?

Similar to:
[Image http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/4627/examplezr.png](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/4627/examplezr.png)

Comment: In related news, check out my suggestion for [Auto-Joining Rooms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59492/auto-join-rooms) - Chat, with less hassle.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/what-sites-should-have-hyperlinking-support-in-chat/57301#57301

Answer (score 1):

We thought about oneboxing all WordPress links, but the problem is, we can't tell it's wordpress without issuing a http request to the target URL.

Oneboxing only works for a truly whitelisted, known set of URLs.The minute you have to HTTP sniff, it becomes unworkable.

Comment: Well blog.stackoverflow.com seems like a natural one, but there is also wordpress.org and blogspot.com