# Onebox Blogoverflow links for chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, blog, onebox

It would be nice if the Community Blog sites (i.e. *.blogoverflow.com) are [oneboxed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onebox) like [the StackOverflow blog links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60006/so-blog-magic-links-for-chat), questions, and so forth.

Jeff mentions that this only works with a whitelist of sites, but I presume that adding *.blogoverflow.com is safe, or auto-adding each community blog when it's started would be simple enough.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/what-sites-should-have-hyperlinking-onebox-support-in-chat/57301#57301

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blog Overflow blogs will now be recognized and parsed as oneboxes.

It's a bit more than just recognizing the url in the whitelist, but also parsing out the pieces of data from the content.